# Select Columns only conaitaing numbers in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am working with a table that has some columns containing numeric values. I want the heading as well as the data of the column (`<th>` and `<td>`) to be aligned right.

I don't know how to select only the columns containing numeric values in `<td>`.

```js
console.log("hi");
```

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

tbody, thead, tfooter {
  text-align: left;
}

tfoot {
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: rgb(222, 227, 224);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <title>Hello!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <caption>
        A summary of the UK's most famous punk bands
      </caption>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Band</th>
          <th scope="col">Year formed</th>
          <th scope="col">No. of Albums</th>
          <th scope="col">Most famous song</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Buzzcocks</th>
          <td>1976</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>Ever fallen in love (with someone you shouldn't've)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">The Clash</th>
          <td>1976</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>London Calling</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">The Damned</th>
          <td>1976</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>Smash it up</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Sex Pistols</th>
          <td>1975</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anarchy in the UK</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Sham 69</th>
          <td>1976</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>If the kids are united</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Siouxsie and the Banshees</th>
          <td>1976</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>Hong Kong Garden</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Stiff Little Fingers</th>
          <td>1977</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>Suspect Device</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">The Stranglers</th>
          <td>1974</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>No More Heroes</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" colspan="2">Total albums</th>
          <td colspan="2">77</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: add number class each of numeric columns and set this class as text-align: right;

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML it appears only the 2nd and 3rd columns are the ones that are numeric.

You can use CSS' `nth` child selector and target the 2nd and 3rd cols in each row.

```
table tbody tr td:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: right;
}
table tbody tr td:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: right;
}
```

You can use the same method for any column in your table footer. But if your table can be more complex then the best option is to use JavaScript to loop over the `<td>` and check if its content is numbers only and then add a class or inline style to it.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: Can I use ```td:nth-child(2,3)``` so that it saves lines?

Comment: @Arittra Use it like `td:nth-child(2),td:nth-child(3)`

Comment: @Arittra it won't work like that, but there are other ways to use it in a shorthand form in the link I have provided. But why do you want to overcomplicate it is my question.

Comment: @DeepakKamat Complicate? I thought it would be simpler.

Comment: `nth-child` is a sort of a complicated selector if you are new to it. Doing things the shorthand way is possible but you might see unexpected results. However what @Bhuwan suggested should work for you.